# How to recombine key and value into an object?

Tags: json, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my Angular app, I am using `ng-repeat` to cycle through all the items in a JSON object I have. So for example, for my JSON object:

```
$scope.animals = 
{
     horse: {
          sound: "Nay",
          legs: 4,
     }
     beaver: {
           sound: "thwack",
           legs: 2
     }
}
```

I want to cycle through to get a list consisting of `Horse, Beaver`i.e.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals">
     <div class="niceBox">
          <h1> {{key}} </h1>
     </div>
</div>
```

but for each animal, I want to have a button that takes the whole object and adds it to a list of my favorite animals. Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals">
         <div class="niceBox">
              <h1> {{key}} </h1>
              <div ng-click="addToFavorites(animal)">Add To Favorites</div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**The Trouble Is** that I can't just pass `animal` as a parameter since I broke up the `ng-repeat` into `(key, value)` already.

How do I reassemble `(key, value)` so I could use the object as a whole?

Comment: What about just passing both `key` and `value` into `addToFavorites`? And how exactly this _single object_ should look like?

Comment: Normally I'd repeat with `ng-repeat="animal in animals` and pass `animal` to `addToFavorites`. Then I get a nice clean object on the other side

Comment: Then what exactly is wrong with `addToFavorites(value)`?

Comment: addToFavorites(key, value) {var animal = {key : value} ; $scope.fav.push(animal); }

Answer (score 3):

Your question is misleading, because there's no original "object" you want to re-assemble - there's just property names and values. If you had a single object for the animal in the first place:

```
var animals = [{
    name: 'horse',
    sound: ...,
    ...
}, {
    name: 'beaver',
    ...
}, ...];
```

there would be nothing to "re-assemble", you'd just use it:

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in animals">
    {{animal.name}}
    <button ng-click="addToFavorites(animal)">...</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by this this

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals">
     <div class="niceBox">
          <h1> {{key}} </h1>
          <div ng-click="addToFavorites(key, value)">Add To Favorites</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.addToFavorites = function(key, value) {
   $scope.animal = {};
   animal[key] = value;
   /** your code **/

}
```